# Scala application initialization. Failing fast or just logging error info

Tags: scala, akka

I have a simple scala+akka application that gets initialized the simplest way it is.

```
object Init extends App {
  implicit val system = ActorSystem("app")


  // Endpoints initialization and binding

  // Scheduling

  // Some other components

}
```

Point is, that while actor system is created and its already there, then if anything goes wrong in the middle (e.g. some missing configuration, port already bound and so on) we can end-up with partly configured but still running application. I'm fully aware that I can just surround everything in try catch and kill app if anything goes wrong but there are also parts of initialization that can fail (in other words, if such initialization fails then we just log the fact and go on with our life). Again, I can imagine a combination of if/try/catch to solve that, but the question is: can i do it better, nicer, cleaner?

Comment: The special thing about the ActorSystem is that it will create a thread-pool with non-daemon threads by default, i.e. it will keep the application alive when the main thread exits.

Comment: You could probably create a `withNewActorSystem(body: => Unit)` which creates the ActorSystem and keeps it running if `body` runs successfully but otherwise shuts it down again on an error.